# How to pass data in Item of repeater onclick Button to javascript file for use in ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a repeater:

```
 <div class="container" id="TourDetail">
    <asp:Repeater ID="RptTourDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODSTTitle" ItemType="Tour" 
EnableViewState="false" OnItemDataBound="RptTourDetail_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
    <ul>
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <li>
             <span class="ForGenHandle">
                <%# Item.TourId %>
             </span>
             <div  id="tright">
                <input runat="server" type="button" name="name" value="INQUIRE" class="Inq" id="InqBtn" />
            </div>
        </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

That it uses my repository to show data.
 I have a button in this Repeater:

```
<input runat="server" type="button" name="name" value="INQUIRE" class="Inq" id="InqBtn" />
```

Onclick on this button opens a box of some data of each Item in repeater.

[image]

I used ajax to do it. Here is my Generic handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["TourID"]);
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ATourDateRep().GetById(x)) );
}
```

and here is my javascript codes:

```
$('.Inq').click(function () {

$.ajax({

url: '../Services/TourDates.ashx?TourID=<%%>',

success: function (e) {
   for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        $('<li />').html("<div>" +
        e[i].TourStartDate + "</div>" + "<div>300$</div>" + " <div>500$</div>").appendTo('#list');
                }
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Does any one know how to pass TourId of each Item of repeater into generic handler as query string? In this line I mean:

`url: '../Services/TourDates.ashx?TourID=<%%>'`

Here is my repository if needed:

```
public class ATourDateRep
{
    private DatabaseEntities model = new DatabaseEntities();
    public List<TourDate> GetById(int Id)
    {
        return model.TourDates.Where(e => e.TourId == Id).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following approach:

1) Modify the `<input>` line as to put `data-TourID` in it:

```
<input runat="server" type="button" data-TourID="<%# Item.TourId %>" name="name" value="INQUIRE" class="Inq" id="InqBtn" />
```

2) Then modify JS code as follows:

```
$('.Inq').click(function () {
    var TourID = $(this).data("TourID"); //read the tour ID
    $.ajax({

        url: '../Services/TourDates.ashx?TourID='+TourID,
        success: function (e) {

           for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                $('<li />').html("<div>" +
                e[i].TourStartDate + "</div>" + "<div>300$</div>" + " <div>500$</div>").appendTo('#list');

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes thank you it has the same problem of the other answer but it solved now. really thank you. I don't know accept which one. both were helpful. thank you

Comment: No problem. Generally I go for first answer in such situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Use [jquery's sibling()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get the span which contains TourId:

```
$('.Inq').click(function () {

$.ajax({

 url: '../Services/TourDates.ashx?TourID=' + $(this).parent().siblings('span').html(), //Modify in this line
 success: function (e) {

   for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {

 $('<li />').html("<div>" +
 e[i].TourStartDate + "</div>" + "<div>300$</div>" + " <div>500$</div>").appendTo('#list');

                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: I test it and `$(this).siblings('span').html()` returns Undefined..!! . really thank you for your help always .

Comment: Does `$(this).parent().siblings('span').html()` work?

Comment: it works fine with the first on-click button  item of repeater .  but on-click on button of next items it doesn't work properly. and it shows the data of button which I first click for each item repeatedly.

Comment: and also on same button for first click it shows the list properly for example if there is 3 dates it shows 3 rows. but in second click on that exact button the list repeated twice .now it shows 6 rows.

Comment: I just saw you have id in your button. This id will be repeated in the repeater. Please remove id, if it is not necessary. Try it. Otherwise I'll show you alternative solution.

Comment: I found the problem. really thank you Mr Bikash. I had to make my list null after close it. it works fine. thank you .